# Get selected key/value of a select box using php

Tags: php, html

how can I get the selected key and value of a HTML select box using php?

```
<select>
    <option value="KEY">VALUE</option>
</select>
```

php code ?

Comment: With PHP, select box's only value that is keys from options are passed.

Comment: one thing you can do :- `<option value="KEY-VALUE">VALUE</option>` and then in your further code `explode with -` and get both `key` and `value`

Answer (score 3):

With PHP, it is not straight forward.

However, with use of array you can achieve it.

Take and array of all options in a common function:

```
$options = array();
$options[1] = 'one';
$options[2] = 'two';
$options[3] = 'three';
```

Display drop down like this:

```
<select name="opt">
<option value=""></option>
<?php
if (! empty($options)) {
 foreach ($options as $key => $val)  {
?>
<option value="<?php echo $key;?>"><?php echo $val;?></option>
<?php
 }
}
?>
</select>
```

And where the form is posted, again get the array.

```
//$options : fetch from common function.

if (isset($_POST['opt'])) {
 echo "key: " . $_POST['opt'];
 echo "<br/>";
 echo "value: " . isset($options[$_POST['opt']]) ? $options[$_POST['opt']] : '';
}
```

Comment: @Anant, it will work with associative arrays also. I have put numeric keys just for understanding purpose.

Comment: @Anant, please read my answer. It covers both key and value from select box.

Answer (score 0):

You must do like this

```
<form class="" action="receiver.php" method="post">
  <select name="mykey">
      <option value="KEY">VALUE</option>
  </select>      
</form>
```

In your receiver.php do in this example

```
$keys = $_POST['mykey'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Name of the `select` is the key and `option` is the value.

```
<select name="KEY">
  <option value="VALUE">VALUE</option>
  <option value="VALUE_2">VALUE</option>
</select>
```

On submit you will get a `KEY => VALUE` pair in `$_GET` or `$_POST` (whatever you use to handle the request)

Answer (score 0):

page1.html:

```
<form action="page2.php" name='add' method="post">
<select name="foo">
    <option value="my_value">my_value</option>
</select>
<input type='submit' name='submit'/>
</form>
```

page2.php:

```
<?php
$result = $_POST['foo'];
echo "result = ".$result."<br>";//output: result = my_value
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using PHP, you could use this:

Put Key and Value as POST data, delimited with a symbol, for example '/'.

**HTML:**

```
<select name="myselect">
    <option value="KEY/VALUE">VALUE</option>
</select>
```

Then in PHP, separate that key with *explode()* function.

**PHP**:

```
$pair = explode("/", $_POST["myselect"]);

$key   = $pair[0];
$value = $pair[1];

print "Key: $key<br />";
print "Value: $value<br />";
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have `form` like this

```
<select name="country">
    <option value="IN_India">India</option>
    <option value="CN_China">China</option>
    <option value="AE_UAE">UAE</option>
</select>
```

Upon submitting it, your `$_POST` would look something like this

```
print_r($_POST);

Array
(
    [country] => IN_India
}
```

Now explde your `$_POST` data and fetch values like this

```
$data = explode('_', filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'country'));
print_r($data);

Array
(
    [0] => IN
    [1] => India
)
```